# how to authenticate whether the token is correct or not?

Tags: c#, web-services

Now, I am facing the difficulties with the web service authentication.The client request the web service . Firsty, the client need to login with user name and password. Then, the server will give the token(random/datetime/randomcode) with expire time back to access the web service. The client can request the web service with the token key. The web service need to authenticate the token whether it is correct or not. 
Now, the following is my code. But I don't know how to continue to authenticate whether the token is correct or not. Please help me!

```
[WebMethod]
public String SampleWebMetho(string username, String Password)
{
  if (username=="demo" && Password== "123")
  {
       string token= Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+username +"|" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss) + 
"|" + Guid.NewGuid().Tostring();
       return token + " is an Authenticated user to access the Web Method";
  }
  else
  {
       return "Access denied for " + username;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using some of the built in authentication schemes?

Comment: Att the very least the server should keep a copy of the token to validate an incoming one.

Answer (score 1):

Store the tokens in a database (i suppose you already have one for the users) and make the webmethods check against it

Comment: I don't want to save in the database because I define the token with the date time. Are there any other way ? If you have sample code, please give me !! I really got the headache about that :(

Comment: If you want to authenticate the web method calls like that you will have to store the tokens somewhere. If you don't want to use a database (why?), you could for example store the active tokens in the application state of the web service.

Comment: If you don't store it at the server every user can make/prolong his own token.